# How do you know the label of a column in the report?

Tags: apex, reporting, dashboard

I use getReportMetadata() and after I use getDetailColumns(), but this is list of API Name of columns in the report. I want discover name this columns. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
DeveloperName = 'abc_Report'];
String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

// Run a report
Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);
// Get the report extended metadata
Reports.ReportExtendedMetadata rmd =   results.getReportExtendedMetadata();

// Get detail columns from extended metadata
Map<String,Reports.DetailColumn> colMap = rmd.getDetailColumnInfo();

for(String key : colMap.KeySet()){
System.debug('Key=' + Key + ' label=' + colMap.get(key).getLabel());
}
```

For more information Refer [ReportExtendedMetadata Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportextendedmetadata.htm)

Comment: That label does *not* always match up with the report label.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - is this what you were thinking of:  for example: a report column labeled `Amount (converted)` in a multi-currency report on Opportunities - such label won't be found in Describe; same for bucket fields

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: FYI, that is just about the least efficient path you could possibly use to `reportId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can describe the report using workbench as described in the [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm). The endpoint is simply:

```
/services/data/<latest API version>/analytics/reports/<report ID>/describe
```

The data you seek is under `reportMetadata` > `detailColumns`:

- reportExtendedMetadata

  - ...
- reportMetadata

  - **detailColumns**
  - ...
- reportTypeMetadata

  - ...

Here is a screenshot of a basic `Report` I set up on `Opportunity` to demonstrate:

[image: Report Run]

And here is the describe information, showing the report labels for these fields:

[image: Report Describe]