# Salesforce Report - Column list

Tags: reporting, python, custom-reports, simple-salesforce

I am trying to see if I can fetch all columns in Reports object.
I have the before

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf_data_cursor = Salesforce(username='mail@mail.com', password='password',security_token='abc', sandbox=False)

df = sf_data_cursor.bulk.Report.query("""SELECT * from Report where Id ='report_id'""")
```

I am trying to see if I can pull all columns in report or is there a way where I can view all existing columns in reports. Could anyone assist. Thanks..

Comment: This may help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146296/how-do-you-know-the-label-of-a-column-in-the-report

Comment: Are you looking for the column *names*, or for the *content* of a report run?

Comment: @DavidReed trying to view the list of all columns currently created so that I could use that in my query

Comment: @DavidReed, actually looking to get extract content of the report as well...

Answer (score 0):

`simple_salesforce` doesn't have direct access to the Reports and Analytics API, which is what you need, but it can call arbitrary Salesforce REST endpoints using the method [`simple_salesforce.Salesforce.restful()`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py#L291). I've used it successfully to talk to the Tooling API, for example.

It looks like you want to be hitting the Report [Describe endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm) to get details about the report's *structure*,

> /services/data/44.0/analytics/reports/YOUR_REPORT_ID/describe

as well as the [Execute Sync endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getreportrundata.htm) to extract the rows from an actual *run* of this report. If you don't care about the column names or report metadata independent of the report run, you may need only Execute Sync.

> /services/data/44.0/analytics/reports/YOUR_REPORT_ID

There's a lengthy example of getting report run data synchronously in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportdata.htm#example_sync_reportexecute).

Note [that there are a variety of limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_limits_limitations.htm) on the Reports and Analytics API, including particularly

> The API returns up to the first 2,000 report rows. You can narrow results using filters.

The report metadata that is returned to you is also, in my opinion, quite complex and can be challenging to work with.

When you query the [Report sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Report) as you are in your question, you don't get back that detailed metadata. Note also that SOQL doesn't support wildcards in the `SELECT` clause, and you probably don't want to be using the Bulk API to query a single record - regular SOQL will be more expeditious.